# Adding uninitialised reference to collection, then initialising it

Tags: java

Consider the following class:

```
public class Test {
    List<Object> colectionA = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Object> colectionB = new LinkedList<>();
    Object A;
    Object B;

    {
        collectionA.add(A);
        collectionB.add(B);
    }

    public void setA{..standard..}
    public void setB{..standard..}
}
```

Now, when instantiating this class, I end up with both collections containing a `null` reference - the setters haven't been called yet.

What I need is that, once the setters are called, the references to be no longer `null`. Essentially I need some indirection - so is the only way to do this to use something like an Atomic Reference?

The context, if you need it is that I've got a class that manages two types of objects - they're all injected at startup (via calling setters), but they're broadly in two groups - at a later point I iterate over the lists to do certain things - but when I do so, despite the setters being called the contents are `null`....

Comment: Are you calling setters? Are are the fields injected? What is there in the setters?

Comment: I'd rather suggest not adding A and B to the collection by default but only in the setters. There it can be checked if the A/B fields had old values and if so can be removed from the collection first

Comment: The setters are normal - they just set the values in the class. They're being called.

Comment: try writing small main and use debugger

Comment: Having thought about it - im a victim of pass by value - the references are copied into the collection by value - so the subsequent update in the setter doesnt affect them. Amateur mistake....

Comment: you want to add the element to collections at the IIB but when your IIB is executed that time your both object A and B are null..

Comment: You apparently don't fully appreciate the distinction between a reference (pointer) value and an object.  All that's placed in the Lists is a reference *value*.  If that reference is null then null gets stored in the List.  The List *does not* somehow maintain a connection to A or B, it only receives the *value* in A or B, just as if it were an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thought about it - im a victim of pass by value - the references are copied into the collection by value - so the subsequent update in the setter doesnt affect them. Amateur mistake....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to give a solution that I would adopt as your problem is not very clear to me. What I would suggest is to create a holder object to store the references of `A` and `B`:

```
    public class Test {
        List<Object> colectionA = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Object> colectionB = new LinkedList<>();
        Holder<Object> holderA;
        Holder<Object> holderB;

        {
            collectionA.add(holderA);
            collectionB.add(holderB);
        }

        public void setA(Object a) {
            this.holderA.set(a);
        }

        public void setB(Object b) {
            this.holderB.set(b);
        }
    }
```

In this case, the references of `A` and `B` will be stored by the holders which are already in the lists.